dimension of intersection of algebraic variety
I know there are similar questions, but everyone uses different approaches and it's complicated to change proofs. In my algebraic geometry course, we're dealing with algebraic variety (topological space locally isomorphic to Zariski closed set in affine spaces over a field K which are separated and finite type) and we defined the dimension of irreducible algebraic variety as the transcendence degree of the field of rational map (=regular maps defined on open dense sets).
My question is about a proposition:

Let $X$, $Y$ be irreducible and closed subsets of a projective space $\Bbb P^n$ such that $\dim(X)+\dim(Y) \geq n$. Then every irreducible components of $X\cap Y$ has dimension at least $\dim(X)+\dim(Y)- n$.

For the proof we used the following fact

Let $X$ be an irreducible and closed subset of projective space $\Bbb P^n$ such that $\dim(X)>0$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane such that $X$ is not contained in $H$. Then $H\cap X$ is closed and each irreducible component has dimension $\dim(X)-1$.

My professor demonstrated the first proposition showing that $X\cap Y$ is isomorphic $\Delta\cap J(X,Y)$ where $\Delta$ is the set $\{[x,x]\}$ of $P^{2n+1}$ and $J(X,Y)$ is a particular irreducible algebraic variety (called the "join"). Well, $\Delta$ is just linear subspace of codimension $n+1$, i.e. intersection of $n+1$ hyperplanes. Then, the professor concluded saying "repeating the fact about intersection with hyperplane we get the thesis for each irreducible components: intersect $J$ with one hyperplane, then take the irreducible components e intersect each with another hyperplane until we get to $\Delta\cap J$".
Here's the problem: is it true that taking the irreducible components of the first intersection and intersecting them with ... I get to the final irreducible components?
I don't know if it is clear my doubt. I know there are proofs that uses Krull's theorem, prime ideals, etc., but we're having a geometrical approach and I'd like to remain in that environment.
There's the chance that the proof is false, but maybe there's something I can learn. If you  know some books about that has this geometrical approach, tell me please.

FYI, you can use $\dim$ to format $\dim$ and $\geq$ to format $\geq$ a bit better. I've fixed things up for you this time - you can look at the edit history to see the full changes.

The proof works as advertised. First, $$\Delta = V(x_0-x_{n+1},\cdots,x_i-x_{n+1+i},\cdots,x_n-x_{2n+1}) = \bigcap_{i=0}^{i=n} V(x_i-x_{n+1+i}),$$ so $J(X,Y)\cap \Delta = J(X,Y)\cap V(x_0-x_{n+1}) \cap \cdots \cap V(x_n-x_{2n+1})$. Next, by the definition of irreducible components, for any algebraic set $S$ whose irreducible components are $S_1,\cdots,S_a$, we have $S=\bigcup_{j=1}^a S_j$, so if $T$ is another algebraic set, we have $S\cap T = (\bigcup_{j=1}^a S_j) \cap T = \bigcup_{j=1}^a (S_j\cap T)$. Putting the two together, we see that working one intersection at a time is equivalent to doing the whole intersection in one go.

Okay, but we defined the dimension of a generic algebraic variety as the maximum of dimension of the irreducible components. Doing like you said I would get that $\Delta\cap V(x_0-x_{n+1})\cap\dots$ is equal to union of some irreducible closed subsets, maybe not the irreducible components. But these days, I found out that every irreducible subset is inside some irreducible components and we proved that closed subsets have dimension $\leq$
of the environment. perhaps, you meant this, thank you.

@AlessandroVagni Intersect $J(X,Y)$ with $V(x_0-x_{n+1})$ to get $Z_1$, with irreducible components $Z_{1,1},\cdots,Z_{1,n_1}$, i.e. $Z_1=\bigcup Z_{1,i}$. Then define $Z_2 = Z_1 \cap V(x_1-x_{n+2})$ with irreducible components $Z_{2,1},\cdots,Z_{2,n_2}$; as $Z_2 = (\bigcup Z_{1,i})\cap V(x_1-x_{n+2})$ we find that the irreducible components of $Z_2$ are the irreducible components of $Z_{1,i}\cap V(x_1-x_{n+2})$ as $i$ varies, and we continue. I don't see your concern with "maybe not the irreducible components" - they're definitely the irred. components. Can you expand on what you don't get?

I was thinking about it. As you said, We have as $i$ varies the irreducible compontents of $Z_{1,i}\cap V(x_1-x_{n+1})$ which overall cover $Z_2$, but we can only say that some of them are the irreducible components not all of them. this triggered me, but actually for the theorem it's not important to take all of them
